# KS Test for Hawkes Process

Tags: statistical-significance, kolmogorov-smirnov-test, point-process, hawkes-process

I am analyzing some data by applying **1d-Hawkes processes**. To evaluate the fit of the model itself (and particularly the chosen kernel, i.e. exponential), I am performing a KS test.

However, it is not entirely clear to me on *which* data the KS has to be performed.
My understanding, at this point, is that the KS test has to be run on **the interarrival times (first-order differences) of the model residuals**. Is this correct?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: this is very abstract and that is probably why it doesnt get answered. Can you add some context and details?

Answer (score 1):

This is correct, this residual analysis is the classic goodness of fit test for the estimation of Hawkes processes. Formally, consider a univariate Hawkes process $\mathcal{T}:=\{t_i: i\in \mathbb{N}^*\}$. Denote by $\lambda$ the conditional intensity of this Hawkes process, and by $\Lambda$ the compensator of this Hawkes process i.e.$\Lambda(t)=\int_0^t \lambda(t)dt$.

Now define for all $i\in \mathbb{N}^*$, $s_{i}=\Lambda(t_i)$ and consider the point process $\mathcal{S}:=\{s_i: i\in \mathbb{N}^*\}$. Then $\mathcal{S}$ is a standard Poisson process. One way to test that $\mathcal{S}$ is a standard Poisson process is indeed by performing a KS test on the residuals $(s_{i+1}-s_{i})$ since under the null hypothesis they should be exponentially distributed with rate $1$.

This classic result can be found in Theorem 1.20 in the thesis of [Linigier (2009)](https://www.research-collection.ethz.ch/handle/20.500.11850/151886), Theorem 7.4.1 in the book of [Daley and Vere-Jones (2003)](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387955414), or earlier in section 3.3 in [Ogata (1988)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2288914?seq=1).

Note that the computation of the residuals of a Hawkes process is expensive in the general case: if $N_T$ jumps are observed, this computation is roughly in $O(N_T^2)$. The generalization of this GOF test to the case of a multidimensonal Hawkes process is straight forward: the time transforms for each dimension of the Hawkes are independent standard Poisson processes.